# How Can I Update the activity(ListView) - android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using services and broadcast receiver, to launch a **listview** (I am using only two activity classes first as first class starts it starts service with it..in the services  hitting a webservice and parsing data, n passing data into the broadcast receiver,
now the data I am getting in **onreceive**, and storing that data into another data...now I want this data to access in my activity class which I wl use for listView...please tell how can I do it..without making that **var. static**.

I also tried this thing within another way please if it is possible in that way too.

There the first screen is getting launch there I kept one button as I click on the button service will start n will do the whole job as I wrote above.....but here as I click the button another activity is being launched which is that listview but that isn't extending listActivity that is extending activity.

so I want to update that list view dynamically how can I do this?

please, any Help is Appreciable.

my code is here where I am getting stuck

```
public class MessageList extends Activity {
 public static final String TAG = MessageList.class.getSimpleName();


 Context mContext;
 public static ArrayList<String> mData;

 public ListView mListView;
 private List<Message> messages;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.maina);
  System.out.println("check bro"+mData);

  System.out.println("In OnCreate of Messagelist class");

  System.out.println("1st");


  System.out.println("3rd");
  mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
  PlaceAdapter adapter = new PlaceAdapter(this, mData);
  mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
   Intent viewMessage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(messages.get(arg2).getLink().toExternalForm()));
   startActivity(viewMessage);
  }
 };


 /* @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
  {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  Intent viewMessage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(messages
  .get(position).getLink().toExternalForm()));
  this.startActivity(viewMessage);
  }*/


 class MessageListBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {



  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   System.out.println("hello");
   System.out.println("final Done");
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   mData = bundle.getStringArrayList("keya");
   Log.d(TAG, "" + mData);

   intent.putExtra("name", mData);


  }

 };
}
```

that message list is the class which is a list view
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than working like this, I would use a class derived from `CursorAdapter` as `Adapter` and let your service store its results in a `ContentProvider` and notify changes on your `ContentResolver` on the same `Uri` you are using in the `CursorAdapter`. That way it will refresh automatically and your data is not lost should anything happen with your app (crash, memory,...). But I reckon this might be a bit of overhead, it all depends on what your webservice exactly does etc.

Comment: hello eMich..thnks for the ans. i am done with this way....actually my task is to do in this way only...i just want to send my data stored in arrayList to my messageList activity...

Comment: Thanks for your reply....please tell me how can i do this...i tried using intent to pass arraylist object but isn't working.....please answer..thanks